# how to implement a mutex using a new synchronization tool that blocks the thread until it's value is larger than a giving bound?

Tags: c++, synchronization, mutex, thread-synchronization

i am studying synchronization  , and i found this topic the hardest thing i came across in coding thus far ! i really need help , and maybe i will start to understand this subject !
i learned about mutex with simple lock and unlock , and i learned about condition varibales and ( that uses signal and wait) i also undesrtand the semaphores , but when i come acros a questions that gives me a new "synchronization" tool and askes me to implement another mutex tools with it i just don't know where to began .

for example let assume i have this new synchronization   tool , and i was asked to implement a simple  mutex using it , how to began solving such a thing ? this is the literally the question ! i am lost any tips ? (plz don't close the question i realy need some tips i am hopeless)

```
typedef struct newSem{
    int value;
} newSem;
// Initialize the newSemto value 0.
void newSem(newSem* h) {
   h->value = 0;
}
// Block until the newSem has value >= bound, then atomically increment its value by delta.
void H(newSem* h, int bound, int delta) {
// This is pseudocode; a real newSem implementation would block, not
// spin, and would ensure that the test and the increment happen in one
// atomic step.
     while (h->value < bound) {
         sched_yield();
     }
     h->value += delta;
}
```

for example to implement this usin the newSem :

```
typedef struct mutex {
newSem h;
} mutex;
void mutex_init(mutex* m) {
//TODO
}
void mutex_lock(mutex* m) {
//TODO
}
void mutex_unlock(mutex* m) {
//TODO
}
```

Comment: C#? looks much more C++ to me...

Comment: that was by mistake i will remove the tag sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a semaphore, then implementing a mutex is trivial since it is basically a sempahore of size 1.

Say you have your semaphore initialized to `0` as shown in the question. Then if you call `H(h, 0, -1)` by two threads, the first one to arrive will go in right away and will set the value to `-1`. The other thread will have to wait because `-1 < 0`. Then the first thread calls `H(h, -1, 1)` to exit and put the value back at `0`, so the second thread can now go in.

Comment: ohhh i am starting to understand ! ok what if the first thread called H(h , -5 ,  -10) for example ? then that thread will insert then the value will be -10 , now other threads can't enter , until for example in the ulock the first thread calls  H(h, -20 , 10 ) ,  then the value (-10 > -20) and the value now is zero , so other threads can enter , but whats the point ? why not using only 0 and -1 and 1 , why we have the option to use other numbers it will not add anything right ?

Comment: @anna That's right! Well, when you have a semaphore, the idea is that you can increase/decrease the numbers to allow more than one thread in the critical sections. But when you implement a mutex, you only need 0/1/-1. The idea of the exercise is to make you realize you can implement a mutex in terms of a semaphore (which is pretty much the easiest exercise of that kind).